# Upgrading from apache 2.2.6 to 2.2.20. A big jump: what might break?

Tags: apache-2.2, backup-restoration

Like the title says, a long-overdue upgrade is needed from Apache 2.2.6 to 2.2.20. I have read this page http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/install.html#upgrading and I have the config.nice file. But I am nervous about what could go wrong. I will make a backup of httpd.config. Could anything be un-fixable?

This is a Solaris 10 box with Apache installed in a custom directory, so the packages from sunfreeware.com won't work, I believe.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It could break a lot of things or it could break nothing. It all depends on whether:

1. You understand your application requirements and dependencies on
   Apache.
2. You have access to the original source that your original apache was
   built off from (with all the custom patches included).
3. You reviewed the release notes and determine what
   chances are made that could impact your application.

That said, if you are nervous about breakage, you don't have to compile it and built it in the same directory as your original. So if your original Apache install is located at:

```
/opt/apache2
```

Compile and install it to:

```
/opt/apache2-test
```

Then copy the apache configs, stop your production apache and then start up your new apache with:

```
/opt/apache2-test/bin/apachectl start
```

Preferably, you should do this in a lab testing environment. :)